# Execute python program using php on server

Tags: php, python, exec

I have a python program that i want to execute from php I already tried "exec,escapeshellcmd,shell_exec,passthru,popen" but no one is giving result.

i already execute "hello word" program successfully but the program that i needed  is not executing and not displaying any error.

```
echo $python = exec("python python/interactive.py");//this file not working
echo $python = passthru("python python/python.py ");// this is working with hello world.
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Yes, `exec` and friends are the right way to tackle this. What is the error you get?

Comment: i'm not getting any error.

Comment: can you share your php code, at least the line where you call `exec`?

Comment: I added code also.

Comment: what is `python/interactive.py` doing? It sounds like it needs a terminal, which of course is not present if you run that python program within a webserver

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look into a python web framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) which are the two main ones if you want to be executing python scripts on the web.This would be the best way to do it.

Comment: actually thing is that the python program that i am using that in not a web app otherwise i not need to execute python in php.